# Python, pandas: Applying Function to Dataframe in Place

Tags: python, pandas

I've constructed a data frame from some signal data. I'd like to perform a DFT on one column of the data frame (using `numpy.fft.fft`) and then have the output be a data frame of the *same* structure, but with the correct column reflecting the application of the function. The *original* data frame is `lead_pts_df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

...(some setup code omitted)

# apply a discrete fast Fourier transform to each data series in the data frame
lead_pts_fft_df = lead_pts_df.magnitude.apply(np.fft.fft)
```

The original data frame looks like this, with both of my columns intact:

[image]

The output data frame post-`.apply(np.fft.fft)` is:

[image]

How can I get a data frame with the original structure intact, but with the DFT function applied to the `magnitude` column?

Comment: Do not post dataframes as images, post them as text. Same goes for output

Comment: Well you can't. Just do ````lead_pts_df.magnitude = lead_pts_df.magnitude.apply(np.fft.fft)````